# Does Israeli law provide for Habeas Corpus and can detained Palestinians raise a petition for it?

Tags: civil-rights, israel, detention, pleadings

According to [a CommonDreams.org article, *"Palestinian Prisoner Hisham Abu Hawash Ends Hunger Strike After Deal With Israel"*](https://www.commondreams.org/news/2022/01/04/palestinian-prisoner-hisham-abu-hawash-ends-hunger-strike-after-deal-israel)

> Palestinians and human rights defenders around the world on Tuesday cheered reports that **Hisham Abu Hawash—who has been imprisoned in Israel without charge for 16 months**—is ending a 141-day hunger strike after reaching an agreement with Israeli officials.

Does *habeas corpus* exist in Israel, and under what terms can a Palestinian in Israeli detention petition for *habeas corpus*? If a non-citizen is detained by Israel is there any limitation that triggers their release, or limits the state from detaining them indefinitely? How was Hisham Abu Hawash detained for 16 months without charge -- did he not raise such a petition?

Comment: Why would you think an English common law doctrine is relevant to Israel?

Comment: @DaleM Do I have to defend my reason for asking a question, even if the underlying assumption is wrong? (Though note this specifically asks **if**, and doesn't assume, _"Does Israeli law provide for Habeous Corpus"_). If it does not, I think that would make a good answer. I was just curious.

Comment: @DaleM Regardless, even if an assumption it seems reasonable to believe it would be in Israeli law as most of the Israeli settlers are from Western Europe (and not Palestine) which has some form of habeous corpus. Habeous corpus is in the European Convention on Human Rights (which has existed in Western Europe since 1950).

Comment: @DaleM Not so fanciful, whether or not it is right. "Israeli law is based mostly on a common law legal system" although it also has significant civil law and religious law influences. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_law Also, it is *habeas corpus*.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thanks for the correct I will [edit] it and fix it.

Comment: @DaleM Evan Carroll is probably thinking of the entitlement provided by the ECHR to those who have been arrested "to take proceedings by which the lawfulness of [their] detention shall be decided speedily by a court and [their] release ordered if the detention is not lawful."  Whether the term "habeas corpus" is employed seems a fairly secondary consideration.

Comment: @DaleM while I agree that EvanCarrol doesn't have to justify their assumptions in asking the question, it is also the case that such an assumption would not be too far off base.  Israel does have a parliamentary government system resembling that of the UK.  So it would hardly be a far out assumption that elements of the British law have made their way into Israel's law.